# css3 cross browser opacity

Tags: css, cross-browser, opacity

I cannot find a way to apply css cross borwser opacity! What is good in IE7, don't go in IE8! and viceversa...
thank you
d

Comment: You might find http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/ useful.

Comment: Your issue is not cross browser but an IE only problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
opacity: 0.5;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
```

try this

Comment: `-ms-filter`, `-moz-opacity`, `-khtml-opacity` not included. See here :http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that makes it work in MSIE browsers, if you follow it correctly.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

Comment: It appears that `-ms-filter` works in IE 8 and 9 but `filter` works in IE 5 to 9 so it's not clear why to use the first one. Perhaps it's a way to provide a valid CSS syntax.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: I don't have any windows computer right now, I'll try to answer this later, cause I don't have a definitive answer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, The link Trufa gave says `-ms-filter` id for IE8 and `filter` is for IE 5-7. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/-- this css-tricks page also says so .