# Transparent Background Color, but only transparency

Tags: css, background, opacity, transparent

I need to add transparency to background color that will change user.
Like if user set background color to #f00 i need to add 0.5 transparency to that.
I cant use rgba() because i get color in #RGB format.
I cant add transparency to all of content.

Comment: css opacity? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386714/css3-cross-browser-opacity

Comment: please guys i think it is usable, many of developers will need your answer

Comment: As stated by others, your only option is rgba if you don't want contents to be transparent as well.

Comment: isn't there any background-image-transparent: option in css 3 or jQuery ?

Comment: Nope. You've got transparent .png images, rgba, or making the whole element transparent with opacity. Why can't you just have users use rgba, or maybe look for a way to convert hex inputs to rgba?

Comment: Are you okay with a javascript solution? Could you get the RGB color and switch it to rgba via script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your help i found the best solution for me 

`list($r,$g,$b) = array_map('hexdec',str_split($colorName,2));
 echo 'rgba('.$r.','.$g.','.$b.',0.5)';`

Thanks to all

Answer (score 3):

You could use a hack if your content is always the same height.

Use three divs.
One div holds the other two.
One div is the background.

One div is the foreground/ non-transparent content.

```
<div id='holder'>
<div id='bg'>

</div>
<div id='content'>
Content is here
</div>
</div>
```

Then in css. make the position of bg and content relative so that the inside divs appear one on top of the other. You might also have to use zIndex or (something like this):

```
#bg {
opactiy: .5;
background-color:#333;
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 300px;
    }

#content {
position: relative;
top: -300px; // negative of the height
left: 0px;
}
```

Admittedly, this could easily get messy! Hope it helps.

Comment: and what if you don't know the height of element ?

Comment: i have created something like this but #bg did absolute becouse the height of parrent element takes from #content, and the last think that wrong is z-index. Now asolute, z-index:10 is higher than relative, z-index:12

Comment: If the content will always be in the same absolute position (like the upper left corner of the page maybe) then you could use position: absolute for both of them--then top and left are the same for both. (I think you are trying this?) Unfortunately, if the content might start anywhere and be any height, I don't know of a way to make them appear one on top of the other.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript can do the trick. I'll assume you're using jQuery since you mentioned it.

[View the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wV7Br/)

If you can use jQuery to get the color, it will return a string in the format of 'rgb(x,x,x)'. Then you can use a function to convert it to an rgba string.

```
function rgbToRgba(rgbString, alpha) {
    rgba = rgbString.replace( 'rgb', 'rgba' );
    rgba = rgba.replace( ')', ',' + alpha + ')' );
    return rgba;
}
```

Then you can set the css with the new value.

```
var color = $('.makeMeRgba').css('background-color');
var rgba = rgbToRgba(color, 0.5);

$('.makeMeRgba').css('background-color', rgba);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use rgba, css opacity should be a option, but will fade all content inside. 
I guess the solution can be a tiny png, not beyond this.

Maybe: Try to use css opacity and create another div inside, and use z-index to control the content opacity.

Comment: nah all of content inside take opacity value